# Why does the Ikarus C42 pitch down when stalled?

Tags: stall, ultralight, ikarus-c42

Apparently, the C42 nose pitches down shortly after stall, like in [this video](https://youtu.be/CLvvIPl4vVA). I know part of the video might be pilot input to recover from the stall, but I've read on various flying forums that this will happen naturally without input anyway. Why is this?

Comment: It's built in to the design of most aircraft as an inherent safety feature - one of the many reasons why flying is remarkably safe.

Comment: I might have to take my instructor up for another few fully developed stalls some time, but that pitch-down movement looks huge, making me think that the CG is quite far forward. What's shown in the video appears similar to what I did the first time we practiced stall recovery, at which time the instructor told me "don't dive". That's in a C42B, so not exactly a C42 but still a very similar aircraft. Really, at least the C42B I've flown has only needed about neutral elevator plus some engine power to recover from a fully developed stall with two adults onboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ikarus C42 is very similar to the Cessna 152 in design and power (but around 500 lbs lighter!).  This is a classic high wing design that is one of the safest aircraft one can fly.  Rock stable on all three axes and very forgiving.  These are a lot of fun to slip, as you will not see a lot of roll coupling with yaw (rudder) input.

As far as the video, this is a fairly normal stall recovery.  As with anything, practice makes perfect.
Properly weighted, this type of plane will not need a hugely aggressive push forward for stall recovery.  Just hold the nose straight with the rudder.

There are really 2 lines of defense in stall recovery with an aircraft properly balanced.  The first is a natural nose down with loss of speed caused by positioning CG ahead of center of lift from wing and trimming with downforce on tail (elevator up).  Because the trim torque is aerodynamic, it has less force when the plane slows down and the nose drops.  Planes set up this way will gently drop out of stall simply by relaxing the elevator.

The second line of defense comes from the surface area of the horizontal stabilizer (as seen from underneath the plane).  If the plane starts sinking in a nose up or level position, vertical motion will help flip the nose down sharply.  This is assisted with down elevator (stick forward).

The key is to hold the nose straight with the rudder.
Do not use the ailerons.  With the Ikarus, simply letting go of the stick should be enough to recover, but it would be highly recommended to take a lesson and learn the limitations and behavior of that plane.

Comment: Not a lot of roll coupling with rudder input in a slip in a Cessna 152?  I'd disagree on that one; the high wing placement creates a strong "dihedral effect".  If we want to talk about WHY that is so it would be good for someone to ask that as an actual question.

Comment: Have you flown one?  Do not understand your need to disagree.  These threads are gratis to all, let's not abuse them.  The reason why high wings don't couple roll with yaw is LOWER CG.  If you don't believe me, check in with the Antonovs.  I know what physics books are teaching, it ain't always  that way in the real world.  What Cessna has done is a masterpiece of force balancing.

Comment: Yes I have flown a Cessna 152 many times and I would say there is substantial coupling between slip and roll.  You've got to be joking if you are saying a high wing configuration has inherently less slip-roll coupling than a low wing, for the same actual physical dihedral angle.  Or that putting the CG way below the wing REDUCES slip-roll coupling.  Post it as a question if you want to discuss further and hear what other folks have to say on this.  Or just see https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/roll.html#sec-other-slip-roll .

Comment: Haven't you ever noticed that high-wing planes are usually designed with less actual dihedral than low-wing planes, for the same general class of aircraft (e.g. general aviation trainers)?  There is a reason for that.

Comment: I have flown a Cessna 172 and one can slam the rudder to the stop and it won't roll worth a damn.  That is what makes it so good in forward slips.

Comment: You are telling me that you don't need to hold any aileron pressure toward the low wing to hold the bank angle constant during a full-rudder slip?  You don't find a full-rudder slip to require cross-controlling to hold stabilized situation (constant heading and bank angle)?  It's no problem to maneuver a Cessna 152 or 172 through reversing turns of up to 30 degrees bank or more, with your hands completely off the yoke.  Just keep the roll rate modest to avoid a rapid rise of the nose as you come through wings-level and a rapid drop of the nose as the bank angle increases.

Comment: Yes, the reason is that low CG provides roll stability,  again see Antonov.  They actually have to put ANHEDRAL in to be able to roll it.  Sir, you have talent, so do others here.  Try listening.

Comment: Again, do a forward slip in a high wing.  That is one of their advantages.  You can work the ailerons BOTH ways.

Comment: See edit to my last comment.  What you are saying is 100% opposite to reality.

Comment: Roll stability is a DIRECT RESULT of slip-roll coupling.  That's where it comes from. The same characteristics that make a plane tend to be stable in hands-off flight, also make it respond strongly to rudder-induced sideslip.  See https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/roll.html#sec-roll-stability  OK enough on this.  Ask it as an actual question if wish to discuss further.

Comment: I don't need to ask it, nor do I need your clearly misguided arguments,  at higher speeds, aerodynamic effects are stronger (obviously). What concerns me most is your rather adolescent desire to impose your ideas.  That is YOUR way of seeing it.  Please consider others.

Comment: And PS, when considering "dihedral effect" in high wings, remember, the area BELOW the CG acts as a vertical fin (fuselage side area and landing gear) to lessen "dihedral effect".  It is not just the wing here.  Cessna knew  this and built a great airplane.  This is pure aerodynamic effect.  The low CG "myth" also helps keep it upright.

Comment: Two different consequences of high-wing configuration-- one, aerodynamic disturbance by fuselage of flow over wing as explored in link I already posted. Two, "parasol" effect that is present even if wing is 100 feet above fuselage so there is no aerodynamic disturbance-- here the wing is high above the center of mass of the whole aircraft, so in a sideslip, wing's drag component acts sideways relative to CG and creates a roll torque. Sure, of course surface area below the CG has the opposite effect. The fact remains in actual practice we see stronger slip-roll coupling with high-wing aircraft.

Comment: We should build models and try this.  I have come to realize the aerodynamic roll coupling force is lessened not by lowering CG, but by adding area UNDER the CG.  The "pendulum" only serves to RESTORE upright condition.  So we must consider side force on landing gear, fuselage, tail etc.  With large displacement of CG and lift (parachute) will tend to rock back and forth easily with side force.  Rather cleverly, putting the wing on top actually raises the CG, but puts more area underneath it.  I do not disagree aerodynamic force at wing/fuse will roll it.

Answer (score 10):

Most aeroplanes are designed with the *Centre of Gravity* being ahead of *Centre of Lift*, so when the aeroplane's wing cannot produce sufficient lift anymore -- due to a high *Angle of Attack*, the nose will drop, therefore, it will decrease the AoA and as the gravity pulls the aeroplane towards earth, the speed will increase which in combination with the lower AoA will hopefully produce enough lift to keep the aeroplane flying again.

In some cases when the CG is not forward of CoL -- e.g. mostly in transport category aeroplanes, the horizontal stabiliser is set/installed on the neutral nose-down *Angle of Incidence*, which makes the aeroplane fly in a more stable manner and will help the stall recovery by pushing to nose-down.

Generally flying in any type of aeroplane with CG aft of CoL is considered a no-no, for the reasons explained above: 1) Flight instability and 2) possibly unrecoverable from a stall -- which in fact is likely to happen because of the displaced CG will tend to increase the AoA which will decrease the speed, until stall happens.

Comment: The second paragraph is incorrect. This configuration (CG is behind CoL of the wing (which is usually called Centre of Pressure, CP)) is _less_ stable and doesn't really help stall recovery. When it becomes actually unstable (CG behind the Neutral Point, NP), the tail will have to be set at a higher AoA than the wing (generally), which means it will likely stall first, causing severe nose-up effect. In general, flight stability is related to NP, not CP.

Comment: Your psychics are a bit off here. To obtain a balance with three forces either all three forces must pass through the same point or they must be parallel with the middle force in the opposite direction of the other two, and the ratio between the distances of the outer forces from the middle force must be the inverse of ratio of the magnitudes of the outer forces.

Comment: Also, your description of why the plane noses down in a stall is wrong. It is not about where the center of gravity and center of lift are positioned, but rather about the relative movement between the two.

Answer (score 6):

Most (if not all) longitudinally stable aircraft will pitch nose down after a stall.

This is because the forward flying surface (regardless of conventional or canard layout) -- or forward portion of the wing, in the case of tailless designs -- must fly at a higher loading and coefficient of lift than the rear in order to maintain stability, so when lift is lost, it will be lost first at the higher-loaded and higher-coefficient surface, which will then start to drop before the lower-loaded or lower-coefficient surface.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your answer it doesn't seem correct. Stall generally starts at the rear of the wing and progresses forward.

Comment: @TomMcW, stall starts at the trailing edge and progresses forward, but the answer says the forward airfoil stalls before the aft airfoil. Tailless designs are always (at least a bit) swept, so the root is the forward airfoil and the tips are the aft airfoil and the twist ensures the proper order of stalling. Untwisted swept wing would stall tip-first, which would cause pitch up, but that is why most swept wings are twisted.

Comment: @JanHudec Non-swept tailless designs exist (Flying Plank, for instance); they depend on reflex airfoils to provide pitch stability.  This keeps the aft portion lifting after the leading portion stalls, so they, too, pitch down after stalling.  If they didn't, they'd be death traps.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, interesting, I didn't see that.

Comment: @JanHudec First, I'm not sure why that part is included. The C42 is not tailless, nor does it have canards or swept wings. That said, it's the phrase "forward" and "aft" airfoil that threw me off. I get what he means now, the root is forward of the tips in a swept wing. It's just confusing wording and really doesn't pertain to the aircraft in question.

Comment: @TomMcW, the part is included because it explains that the behaviour is universal. And forward and aft airfoil are somewhat common terms when discussing stability requirements.

Comment: I guess if it said forward and aft *portion" of the airfoil it would be less confusing. But in the situation at hand, an unswept wing, a twisted airfoil would be intended to maintain aileron authority and not contribute to the pitch down effect. That would be entirely due to the center of lift being aft of the cog. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @TomMcW Whether in the simple case of conventional layout, no sweep, or the extreme of a no-sweep tailless, the CL is never actually aft of the CG.  The combined CL of the entire lifting surface -- wing, stabilizer, third surface if present, fuselage, and external payload if any -- must coincide with the CG in steady state flight, else you'll have a pitching moment.  The tendency to nose up with speed increase is pitch stability, and it requires something forward to have a higher coefficient than things aft -- else your airframe is unstable.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: From what I've read, the original Flyer was deliberately designed so that it wouldn't pitch down, nor be able to regain airspeed, if it stalled.  This didn't make it a death trap, however, since it would descend with a largely uncontrollable but safe velocity and attitude.  Such a design wouldn't be suitable for e.g. flying over buildings or water, but had its advantages back in the day.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm still confused, but I don't want to string out the comments. If you feel like it, hit me up on chat

Comment: @supercat As I understand it, the Wrights built the 1903 Flyer to be marginally unstable because they weren't certain they could control it if it was "too stable".  After they found out how unstable it was, they built the next model with a reasonable stability margin.  The Flyer wasn't a deathtrap only because it flew at 20-30 feet, at 35 mph, instead of a few hundred feet at 70 mph.

Comment: @TomMcW I can't chat now, but I recommend reading up on design for stability, especially as relates to model airplanes.  With no pilot aboard, they must typify stability.  If you can find it, Keith Laumer's model airplane book is quite good.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: I don't think terminal velocity for an object of the Flyer's shape and weight would be very high if it maintained an attitude with the wings roughly horizontal.  The first flying fatality occurred in a plane which had a control cable break, but I'm sure there had been many stall-induced crashes before that, from altitudes far greater than 20-30 feet.

Comment: @supercat The Flyer was heavier than it looked -- 600+ lb dry, or a bit more than double what a Part 103 ultralight the same size would weigh.  Much of that weight was the engine.  Terminal velocity in a deep stall would have been plenty to kill, especially with 200+ lb of engine sitting beside you and a structure that would collapse on impact.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Hmm... I forget the title of the coffee-table book I'd read about it, but it had seemed authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

As a stall is approached, the center of lift moves slowly forward. The pilot will compensate for this with either back-pressure on the stick/yoke or by trimming the aircraft. When the stall occurs the center of lift suddenly and rapidly moves towards the rear of the aircraft. Since the aircraft was balanced before, moving the force of lift backwards will cause the rear of the aircraft to rotate upwards, and the nose to drop. In a traditional aircraft configuration, the wing will stall before the horizontal stabilizer. The horizontal stabilizer normally produces lift in the downwards direction just incase it does stall, that way the nose would automatically drop. Canard configurations achieve the same effect by having the horizontal stabilizer produce positive lift and stall before the wing.

Comment: I don't understand how the center of lift moving forward would cause a nose-down moment.

Comment: It is the rapid movement of the Center of loft to the rear that causes the nose to drop. The forward movement earlier on may or may not affect trim depending on how slowly the aircraft is brought to the stall as well as different design characteristics pertaining to the wing and horizontal stabilizer.